# Is there a safe way to use max-height CSS media-query

Tags: html, ios, css, google-chrome

As far as can tell it's impossible to use the max-height media query usefully because of Chrome 67 on iOS.

The issue is that as the users scroll up and down Chrome adds and removes the address bar. As it does this it changes the max-height which means that if you're using a max-height media query to change the height of something than anything below the something will jump when the users scrolls up or down.

For example I have an image that's 300x500 but on a short screen I wanted to make sure it didn't fill the screen so I have something like this

```
@media (max-height: 700px) {
  img {
    max-height: 400px;
  }
}
```

Effectively "if the screen is short make the image short too"

But what happens on Chrome iOS is that on iPhone X as it adds and removes the address bar it triggers the media query

[image]

If there's a few images on the page and the user is near the bottom as they scroll up and down the page will jump half a screen or more.

Note that Safari on iOS doesn't have this issue even though it also makes the address bar appear and disappear.

I can choose some other `max-height` to trigger on but of course the same thing could happen on any phone of any height so it's looking like using `max-height` to trigger things is hopelessly broken?

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: iOS Safari doesn't consider the header and footer part of the viewport, whereas Chrome does. Since this is such a fundamental difference between browsers, it may not get fixed for a while. If you want to "cheat" you can always try to force the navbar to be visible on the page.

Answer (score 2):

turns out this is a bug in iOS WkWebView and/or Chrome iOS. The bug is tracked here so if they manage to fix it then I guess the problem is solved.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=720048